# ¿Como puedo hacer un Update de un array en concreto con angular firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

La cosa es que yo tengo esto en mi cloud firestore:

```
  randomID: {
        titulo: "La tienda en casa",
        productos: 
          [0]: {
             titulo: "plátano",
             desc: "es amarillo",
             id: 2
           }

          [1]: {
             titulo: "manzana",
             desc: "es verde",
             id: 2
           }
      }
```

Como puedo hacer un update en el array, si por ejemplo, tengo un botón que me da un ID aleatorio entre los id's existentes `(ej.1)`, y quiero que buscando en `firebase` con `AngularFirestore`, entre todos los datos que existen en `productos`, encuentre el `ID` generado por el botón en este caso `ID = 1`, y pueda cambiar los datos de ese `array`, en concreto la `descripción`, cambiar de `es verde` a `es ácida`.

> No tengo código porque no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

si estas trabajando desde Angular, sin duda puedes usar la librería Oficial para Firebase, AngularFire2, y a través de ella puedes usar muchos útiles métodos, a continuación te dejo un código de ejemplo de un servicio para hacer un update tal como quieres:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductoService {

  arregloDeProductos: any[] = [];
  private coleccionDeProductos: AngularFirestoreCollection<ProductoModel>;

  constructor(public firebase: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.coleccionDeProductos = this.firebase.collection<ProductoModel>('productos');
  }

  actualizarProducto( producto ) {
    return this.coleccionDeProductos.doc( producto.id ).set( producto ); 
  }
}
```

Y bueno está claro que para que esto funcione:

1. Primero debes instalar la librería Angular Fire2 mediante el siguiente comando:

```js
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

2. Luego debes importar los módulos de Firebase que necesites, imagino que en tu caso quieres guardar productos y tal vez imágenes, entonces debes tu app.module.ts debe lucir así:

```js
// Angular Fire 2 & Firebase
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

Bueno Noooma me cuentas como te va con todo esto :)